# bootstrap-vue table td element styling

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, bootstrap-vue

I have an issue by giving styles to the `<td>` tag of b-table element.

This is the template:

```
    <b-table
      :fields="fields"
      :items="items"
      class="mx-1 mt-2"
      v-if="items && items.length > 0"
    >
      <template
        slot="email"
        slot-scope="row"
      >
        <div :title="row.item.email">
          <p class="user-email">{{row.item.email}}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

And this is the fields:

```
    fields: [
      { key: "email", label: "Email"},
      { key: "user", label: "Name" },
      { key: "role", label: "Role" }
    ],
```

I want to give max-width of 300px to the `<td>` of this table. 
Please help!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `max-width` via CSS?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't responding

Answer (score 25):

You can set the `tdClass` property inside of your field object.
But `tdClass` just accepts a string or an array, not an object. So you can only reference to a css class.

```
fields: [
      { key: "email", label: "Email", tdClass: 'nameOfTheClass'},
      { key: "user", label: "Name" , tdClass: 'nameOfTheClass'},
      { key: "role", label: "Role" , tdClass: 'nameOfTheClass'}
]
```

and in your CSS:

```
.nameOfTheClass {
   max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried it here again, just to be sure and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/yzjudf6b/1/ By using the inspector you can see that both style attributes are assigned to the `td` element

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, maybe you could create a small snippet?

Comment: I see it works on JSFiddle. But it don't work on my machine, sorry :/

Comment: Are you using the latest version of bootstrap-vue?

Comment: @ArevshatyanGegham Please inspect the affected elements and make sure the styling isn't being overridden by something else.

Comment: Styling isn't being overridden. When I inspect the element I see the class that I gave to it, but there's no styling shown in the CSS. When I add the style in the inspector it works properly!

Comment: Does your `<style>` tag has the scoped attribute?

Comment: Thanks Jns, that solved it for me. I was using `<style scoped>.myclass{}</style>`. Removing the scoped worked. I also needed `!important`.

Comment: It wasn't working for me directly. I had to set `tdClass: 'nameOfTheClass'` in view/component & set `.nameOfTheClass {max-width: 300px;}` specifically in `App.vue` for some reason. I guess there was some issue with scope

Answer (score 13):

Here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table you can read:
"class, thClass, tdClass etc. will not work with classes that are defined in scoped CSS".
So this may be the case it was not working for you.
If you want to style your thead, you can use thStyle property in your field object i.e:

```
{
   key: 'test', label: 'Test', thStyle: { backgroundColor: '#3eef33'}
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

The only way i managed to get it to work for me is by using Vue's [Deep Selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) on the table and targeting td tag.

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
/* ::v-deep/ .table > tbody > tr > td { */
/deep/ .table > tbody > tr > td {
max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

I hope this helps someone out there.!!