# How to apply b-table fields thClass or tdClass or class

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```
<template>
 <b-table
   striped hover
   :fields="fields"
   :items="list"
   class="table"
 >
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .table >>> .bTableThStyle {
    max-width: 12rem;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
<script lang="ts">
 import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
 @Component(...)
 export default class className extends Vue {
  fields = [
   {label: 'index', key: 'index', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true},
   {label: 'title', key: 'title', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, tbClass: 'bTableThStyle'},
  ];
 }
</script>
```

At the code snippet above, I tried to apply CSS only to the event name in the fields of the b-table using tbClass.
(Reference URL: [bootstrap-vue table td element styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744011/bootstrap-vue-table-td-element-styling))

I't does not work.

The goal is to style just one field for fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `style`, you can try with this code below:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  /** or use this class: table thead th.bTableThStyle { ... } */
  .table .bTableThStyle {
    max-width: 12rem !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  }
</style>
```

> Make sure, your `.bTableThStyle`  has been added to your html when you inspect your element.

Comment: When using scoped styles, you will need to use [vue-loader's deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) to target inner elements of a child component.